# Variable in Flow

Tags: query, flow

​Could you please advise
   1. can I use cross object formula field in a process builder to pass variable value to flow
    2. Can prcoess builder execute even if the record is updated from back end ?

Answer (score 0):

1.yes
2. is updated from back end means data loader? then yes

Comment: Hi Not by data loader by code am updating the value . Will it execute if i update through code .

Comment: I think it would not if you will be updating a record from the object referenced in the formula. But if you are updating the object that you have created Process for, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,surely,process builder will execute on any kind of DML on the sobject